# Corrupt QImage after a signal/slot call between two different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, image, qt, signals-slots

I am sending a QImage via a signal/slot mechanism, between two threads (a background DB thread and a GUI thread). The GUI slot receives a corrupt image (some pixels are randomly corrupt). I have done this already, and never had any issue. What could be wrong?

The programm is too complex to be included here, but here is some relevant information:

1. The sending thread (DB) is a regular QThread, with an event loop, running a DataBaseInterface QObject class which was moved to this thread
2. The signal/slot connection was done after the moveToThread, so each object is in its final thread. This means that explicitely using QueuedConnection makes no difference as this is already the case.
3. The QImage is not sent directly in the signal/slot parameters, but within a struct which contains other stuff (three QVectors). This struct was registered using:

   ```
   qRegisterMetaType<MyStruct>("MyStruct");
   ```
4. The QImage was not created using an external buffer, but with the (width, height, Format) constructor. So the image buffer is maintained internally and thus implicitely shared
5. If I save the image to disk in the DB thread just after emitting the signal, it is good. If I save it just at the beginning of the slot, it is corrupt.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll really need to post a test case for this, since I can't reproduce it at all. Remember: single file.

Comment: Damn... I can try, but since the whole stuff depends on SQL connection delays, etc..., I bet the problem will disappear as soon as the delays are removed

Comment: Some other code is writing over memory it doesn't own and destroys the image data. You can easily add delays and things like that to your test case, but they will prove immaterial. Instead of depending on delays, insert explicit synchronization primitives to synchronize the worker thread with the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, o that the image is not corrupted you should ensure the following:each data containing the structure that are sending must have copy constructor, avoids sending data pointer and if you do it sure that these reside in memory heap, the connection type for these cases is Qt::QueuedConnection, the label on establish the image that you think should be configured as follows:

```
label->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base);
label->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
label->setScaledContents(true);
```

the slot where the image or comes your structure should look like this, in my case with opencv and QT is:

```
void interfaz::actImagenFromVideo(cv::Mat myImage)
{
QImage image(myImage.data,myImage.cols, myImage.rows, myImage.step, QImage::Format_RGB888 );
label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image.rgbSwapped()));
}
```

he run function of your QThread should look something like:

```
void THREAD::run()
{

 while(true){
 {
 QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
 if (stopped) {
  stopped = false;
  break;
  }
  }

  cap>>videoIn;
  emit image_ready(videoIn.clone()); //the use of cv::Mat::clone() is very   important in openCV

  }

 }
```